# List of implicit ARIA roles of html elements

Tags: html, wai-aria

I have looked for documentation about **implicit html roles** but not found something listing the default roles of html elements.

This article: https://www.webteacher.ws/2014/07/23/implicit-aria-roles/ is interesting but does not provide an exhaustive list of the default roles of html elements.

Can someone please provide advise or links to a relevant resource documenting the implicit roles of html elements?

Thanks in advance

**edit**: maybe a IDE can tell me what the default role is for a given html element. If that is the case how can I find this information, say with Intellij?

**edit 2**: This link is interesting but the list is **by role** and not **by html element**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found exhaustive, up-to-date and relevant documentation that answers my question. See here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance

As stated in my question, the above link is also interesting and relevant:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles

Answer (score 1):

Here ARIA Examples with HTML Techniques and ARIA Techniques:

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/HTML5.html